# Creating buffer around line segments based on custom values for each line

Tags: geopandas

I have a line shapefile (feature count > 600000) which has three fields: id, geometry, bufferwidth.

Which means, each line has its own buffer width.

How can I create for each feature a buffer with the relevant bufferwidth and store the created polygon? At best, as a result, I would have for each line feature a bufferpolygon within one polygon shapefile. This, as with the buffers I need to fetch point features subsequently.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS or GeoPandas?
If not, I would be open to try it with another tool or method.

Comment: Are you asking how to [buffer based on an attribute](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=buffer#buffer:~:text=Input%20vector%20layer-,Distance,-DISTANCE)?

Comment: Hi @Erik Yes, I would like to buffer based on an attribute of the line-object. 
Thank you for showing the several options of buffering in QGIS, but I couldn't find any of the buffer provide the option to set the buffer width according to a an attribute of a geometry?

Comment: Ever heard of data defined override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the buffer function like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/bufferlines.geojson")
#df.columns
#Out[3]: Index(['id', 'bufferwidth', 'geometry'], dtype='object')

df["bufferpoly"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.buffer(distance=x["bufferwidth"]), axis=1)
```